# Why does the bind function return -1(bind fails)?

Tags: c, client, server

I am trying to bind a socket to the IP address and the port on which it will listen for connections. Here is my relevant code(w comments and debug print statements)

```
#define PORTNUM 2345
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        // socket info about client connecting to server
        struct sockaddr_in dest;
        //socket info about server 
        struct sockaddr_in serv; 
        //socket used to listen for incoming connections 
        int mysocket;            
        //zero the struct before filling the fields 
        memset(&serv, 0, sizeof(serv)); 
        //set connection type to tcp/ip           
        serv.sin_family = AF_INET; 
        //set should be be bound to ip of the machine on which process currently executing               
          serv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
         //set server port number
         serv.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);
          //create the socket to liste for connection 
           mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        printf("value of socket:%d\n", mysocket);
         // bind serv information to mysocket 
      int v=  bind(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serv, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
      printf("value of bind: %d\n", v);

       return 1;   
}
```

Here are my debug print statements when i run my code

```
Value of socket: 3
Value of bind: -1
```

When I read the documentation http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind, I saw that the bind function will return a -1 for error(bind failed). Based on my code, does anyone know why this operation failed? I looked over my code and i think i have everything set up (all the commenting). I even made sure that the port number I used was in the range assigned to applications(1024 - 49151). Based on http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html, I know that the socket was created successfully(return value of 3, not -1)

Comment: Call `perror("bind");` to print the actual error.  See in that documentation you linked all the errors bind can return?  Those are saved in a global variable called `errno` that you can directly access by including `errno.h`.  `perror()` is a helper function declared in `stdio.h`.

Comment: Where do i call perror? Right after the call to bind?

Comment: Yes, before you do anything else.  You want your code to be like `int v = bind(...); if( v < 0 ) { perror("bind"); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
./err 
value of socket:3
value of bind: 0
```

So, it works. There's nothing wrong with the code. Most probably the port should be already in use by another program, or an earlier version of your program is in a cleanup state, making the port busy. To confirm, use perror() right after calling bind. Also look for the SO_REUSEADDR socket option to allow binding on a port that is in cleanup state.

Comment: Yeah it's weird now it says bind:Success. It must be that an earlier version of the program was in a cleanup state. How long do you usually have to wait for that earlier version to exit out of cleanup state?

Comment: I ran it again and it said "bind: Address in use". Is there a time period you have to wait before bind works again?

Comment: It may be 60 seconds or more. You definitely need to enable SO_REUSEADDR to allow fast binding.